# combine two list and sort recursively

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I'm trying to define a function named combine to take two lists as parameters and combine them into one sorted list recursively.

```
def combine (l1,l2):
    if l1 == []:
        return l2
    elif l2 == []:
        return l1
    elif l1 == [] and l2 == []:
        return []
    sort_l = []
    index = 0
    for num in l1:
        if num <= l2[0]:
            sort_l.append(num)
            index += 1
        else:
            return combine(l2, l1[index:])
    return sort_l + l2
```

It gives me:

```
combine([1,3,5,7,9],[0,2,4,6,8]) -> [8, 9]
```

but should:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Any advice???

Comment: sort_l shouldn't be initialized inside the function. Each recursive call will reinitialize it to empty.

Comment: "combine them into one sorted list recursively" - are you sure this is the part where you were supposed to be using recursion? It sounds like this may be intended to be a component of a mergesort algorithm, where the mergesort would naturally use recursion, but this component shouldn't.

Comment: did you forget to mention in the question, that the 2 input lists are sorted?

Comment: @user2357112 it seems he is trying to write the merge part of the mergesort algo for algo/ds exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. But, you are reallocating the `sort_l` in every recursive call. You need to either define it outside the function or pass it with every function call, after creating only once:

```
sort_l = []

def combine (l1,l2):
    if l1 == []:
        return l2
    elif l2 == []:
        return l1
    elif l1 == [] and l2 == []:
        return []
    index = 0
    for num in l1:
        if num <= l2[0]:
            sort_l.append(num)
            index += 1
        else:
            return combine(l2, l1[index:]) 
    return sort_l + l2
```

or

```
def combine (l1,l2, sort_l=None):
    if sort_l is None:
       sort_l = []
    if l1 == []:
        return l2
    elif l2 == []:
        return l1
    elif l1 == [] and l2 == []:
        return []
    index = 0
    for num in l1:
        if num <= l2[0]:
            sort_l.append(num)
            index += 1
        else:
            return combine(l2, l1[index:], sort_l) # pass it here
    return sort_l + l2

combine([1,3,5,7,9],[0,2,4,6,8]) # Don't pass any list, it will be created in first call.
```

Answer (score 4):

python lists can be combined with a simple `+` and the builtin function [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) will sort items in the list for you.

```
sorted(l1 + l2) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

program should be like this:

```
sort_l = []
def combine (l1,l2):
    if l1 == []:
        return l2
    elif l2 == []:
        return l1
    elif l1 == [] and l2 == []:
        return []
    index = 0
    for num in l1:
        if num <= l2[0]:
            sort_l.append(num)
            index += 1
        else:
            return combine(l2, l1[index:])
    return sort_l + l2
print(combine([1,3,5,7,9],[0,2,4,6,8]))
```

Comment: please state your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  The trick is to put the smaller of `l1[0]` and `l2[0]` in front of the result of the recursive `combine()`:

```
def combine (l1,l2):
    if l1 == []:
        return l2
    if l2 == []:
        return l1
    if l1[0] <= l2[0]:
        return [l1[0]] + combine(l1[1:], l2)
    return [l2[0]] + combine(l1, l2[1:])
```