# How can I use recursion to add two lists together?

Tags: python

For example, say I have

```
a = [1, 3, 9]
b = [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

and I want to return a new list(n) in sequential order:

```
n = [1,1,2,3,4,5,9] by using recursion.
```

I have tried doing this using a standard recursion method but my issue is that whenever I create a new list inside the recursive function, its value is always set to [] again during the recursive call. Is there any way to have n not go back to being empty?

```
def recur(a,b):
    if a[0] <= b[0]:
        n.append(a[0])
        return (merge(a[1:], b))
```

Comment: Why use recursion when you can do `sorted(a + b)`?

Comment: I know I can just add and sort but I want to use recursion because I'm currently learning recursion methods.

Comment: Please give us an example of your recursive function

Comment: Why is 5 before 9 in the output? Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I just updated it

Comment: Because I want to add the values in order

Comment: You could implement any recursive sorting algorithm (there are dozens) to which you pass `a + b`.

Comment: here you have few solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990057/combine-two-list-and-sort-recursively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (off the top of my head, may have mistakes):

```
def merge_sorted(a, b):
    if not a:
        return b
    if not b
        return a

    if a[0] < b[0]:
        return [a[0]] + merge_sorted(a[1:], b)
    return [b[0]] + merge_sorted(a, b[1:])
```

I suggest implementing a few versions, and try finding some yourself, if learning recursion is your goal. One version could be similar to what you started - returning the result in a 3d list (so you would need a 3d argument. The other option is a global which i don't like personally). The recipe for me is always the same:

1. Define the stop condition. In the above, obviously if one of the inputs is empty, and the other is sorted, than the other one is indeed the result.
2. From that infer the returning invariant - in the above case is that the result of `merge_sorted` returns a proper merger of the lists.
3. Given the invariant, construct the recursive call reducing the size of the input.

This is very similar to proof by induction (identical?).

Comment: thank you for your great tips on recursion. I had several more problems that I was able to figure out on my own by thinking about your tips! very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
def recur(array):
    ret = []
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array;
    half  = int(len(array) / 2)
    lower = recur(array[:half])
    upper = recur(array[half:])
    lower_len = len(lower)
    upper_len = len(upper)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i != lower_len or j != upper_len:
        if( i != lower_len and (j == upper_len or lower[i] < upper[j])):
            ret.append(lower[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            ret.append(upper[j])
            j += 1

    return ret

a = [1, 3, 9]
b = [1, 2, 4, 5]
print(a+b)           #[1, 3, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5]
print(recur(a+b))    #[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 3, 9]
b = [1, 2, 4, 5] 
c=[]
def recurse(a,b,c):
    if len(a)==0 and len(b)==0:
        pass
    elif len(a)==0 and len(b)!=0:
        c.extend(b)
    elif len(a)!=0 and len(b)==0:
        c.extend(a)
    elif a[0]<b[0]:
        c.append(a[0])
        del a[0]
        recurse(a,b,c)
    else:
        c.append(b[0])
        del b[0]
        recurse(a,b,c)
recurse(a,b,c)
```

Explanation:

1.Create an empty list c

2.1st If: if both 'a' & 'b' are empty, your recursion is complete

3.1st elif:If only 'a' is empty, extend() all value of 'b' to 'c' & recursion complete

4.2nd elif: similar to 1st elif but vice versa

5.If both are non-empty, check for 1st element of 'a' & 'b'. Whichever is lower, append to 'c' & delete, recursively call 'recurse'

Though it considers both 'a' & 'b' are sorted as in the example above